# xVal Client side Validation with validation Callout

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, xval, callouts

Im using MVC data annotation with xVal Client Validation on a form.  How do I implement something like the a asp.net validation callout extender instead of display red error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this.  You can modify the xVal javascript file, by replacing the normal `"<span class='field-validation-error'>..."` javascript generated markup error message with custom markup and styling that will look like the callout extender.